# How to execute custom C++ binary on HDFS file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, bigdata, hadoop2

I have custom c++ binaries which reads raw data file and writes derived data file. The size of files are in 100Gbs. Moreover, I would like to process multiple 100Gb files in parallel and generated a materialized view of derived metadata. Hence, map-reduce paradigm seems more scalable.

I am a newbie in Hadoop ecosystem. I have used Ambari to setup a Hadoop cluster on AWS. I have built my custom C++ binaries on every data node and loaded the raw data files on HDFS. What are my options to execute this binary on HDFS files?

Comment: Please consider using appropriate tags for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop streaming is the simplest way to run non-Java applications as MapReduce.

Refer to [Hadoop Streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html) for more details.